# Unfortunately application stopped

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am getting the below error

```
05-08 01:03:16.003: D/dalvikvm(1147): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 46K, 4% free 3036K/3156K, paused 98ms, total 102ms
    05-08 01:03:16.313: D/dalvikvm(1147): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 4% free 3386K/3508K, paused 42ms, total 43ms
    05-08 01:03:17.263: D/gralloc_goldfish(1147): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
    05-08 01:03:21.563: D/dalvikvm(1147): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 2% free 3850K/3928K, paused 139ms, total 146ms
    05-08 01:03:21.733: D/dalvikvm(1147): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 3% free 3944K/4028K, paused 139ms, total 140ms
    05-08 01:03:21.813: I/dalvikvm-heap(1147): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.990MB for 1127536-byte allocation
    05-08 01:03:22.043: D/dalvikvm(1147): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 5045K/5132K, paused 224ms, total 224ms
    05-08 01:03:23.943: D/AndroidRuntime(1147): Shutting down VM
    05-08 01:03:23.943: W/dalvikvm(1147): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1ad3ba8)
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147): Process: com.example.crosswordapp, PID: 1147
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.crosswordapp/com.example.crosswordapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at com.example.crosswordapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:139)
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    05-08 01:03:24.003: E/AndroidRuntime(1147):     ... 11 more
    05-08 01:08:24.593: I/Process(1147): Sending signal. PID: 1147 SIG: 9
```

This is my Log-cat

My MainActivity.java is this

```
String output = "-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,;-,a,-,c,g,-,-,-,g,-,-,-,-,;c,s,-,o,a,-,-,-,r,-,-,-,-,;o,s,-,h,t,-,-,-,o,-,-,-,-,;m,e,-,o,h,-,-,-,u,p,-,-,-,;p,m,-,r,e,-,-,-,p,e,-,-,-,;a,b,s,t,r,a,c,t,i,o,n,-,-,;n,l,-,-,i,-,-,-,n,p,-,-,-,;y,a,-,-,n,-,-,-,g,l,-,-,-,;-,g,-,-,g,-,-,-,-,e,-,-,-,;-,e,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,;-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,;-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,;";
        String[][] populate = new String[13][13];

        String[] outputRow = output.split(";");
        // Log.i(outputRow+"output");
        for (int i = 0; i < outputRow.length; i++) {
            String[] outputCol = outputRow[i].split(",");
            for (int j = 0; j < outputCol.length; j++) {

                buttons[i][j] = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

                buttons[i][j].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white);
                if (populate[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {
                    buttons[i][j].setText(populate[i][j]);
                    buttons[i][j].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);
                    buttons[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    buttons[i][j].setText(populate[i][j]);
                    buttons[i][j].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white);
                    buttons[i][j].setEnabled(true);
                }
```

Here I need to display the grid with string output which I return in the program. In this I am not getting any error but while running the app it is showing:

> Unfortunately application stopped.

Here 139 line is

> if (populate[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase("-"))

Here it is showing that null pointer exception. I don't know why it is coming.

Comment: The answers below are correct. In general, when you do things like that, write it in a manner that's NPE proof, such as `"-".equalsIgnoreCase( populate[i][j] )` -- this way, even if that array cell is null, you can still compare it to the string literal without having to do a null check.

Comment: i done like this, but the output is show all white buttons. The output is not correct

Comment: Of course it's not working -- you still didn't fix the problem, but you avoided the crash. See the answers below -- you never populated `populate`, so that's where your problem is.

Comment: if(outputCol[i]=="-"){
     populate[i][j] = " ";}
   else{
    }
If i wrote this lines in the for loop(above mainactivity.this) what statements i should write in the else part to print the characters in the same position. Is this way is correct

Comment: `outputCol[i]=="-"` would be wrong under any circumstance. String comparison is done with `equals`, such as `"-".equals(outputCol[i])`. What you write in your else depends on what you're trying to do. It's all a bit convoluted and messy. What *are* you trying to do?

Comment: it's working but the text inside the button is not printing in the middle it is just printing in the left(It's looking like hiding the text). If you don't mind can you please tell me how to print the text exactly in the middle.

Comment: Ya i looked after documentation and here i specified the statement as buttons[i][j].setTextAllignment="center" but still it is not displaying in center. How to do this..

Comment: You were able to compile this `buttons[i][j].setTextAllignment="center"`? HOW?

Answer (score 2):

Although you have defined `String[][] populate = new String[13][13];`
I dont see in your code where you are populating it.
That leads to `populate[i][j]` being null and you get that exception thrown out.
Try to put values inside populate[][] before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that you have a NULL POINTER EXCEPTION, that means one of the strings is not taking any value and is kept null. so when you try to access that string, the error occurs. 
Try to first print all your strings and see which string is storing what data, maybe that way you can solve your error.

Comment: To print the value i am using like Log.i("buttons"+i+j) but it showing the error in the place of i(Log.i). how to rectify this..

Comment: Before the loop starts, print the value of populate inside a FOR LOOP. Also inside the other for loop that you are using, print both the strings with i and j values so you know what every column contains. Use a simple system.out.println() statement to print and check the log there you will get the output.

Comment: it's ok,The text inside the button is not printing in the middle it is just printing in the left(It's looking like hiding the text). If you don't mind can you please tell me how to print the text exactly in the middle.

Comment: just align the text at 'center'...i think that will work. But looking at your code, i just think that the populate string needs to be initialized. then you will not get error. if you look at your code, then you will find that you are just declaring the populate string and not giving it any value. when we declare a string it takes the value null, hence the null pointer exception. so first give some value to populate, i am sure that will solve the problem.

Comment: here i specified the statement as buttons[i][j].setTextAllignment="center" but still it is not displaying in center. How to do this..

Comment: looks like it is printing some space and then printing the value, so align it to the right, that way after the spaces the text will come in the center.